# How to create mysql statement with group by each day (Monday - Sunday as column) in a week and total

Tags: mysql

**My Data**

Employee table

```
|------|--------------| 
|   ID |    Name      | 
|------|--------------| 
|    1 |    Peter     | 
|    2 |    Davis     | 
|    3 |    Mike      | 
|------|--------------|
```

Time table

```
|-----|-----------|---------------------|---------------------|-------------| 
|  No |   EmpID   |       TimeIn        |       TimeOut       | Total(hr.)  |
|-----|-----------|---------------------|---------------------|-------------| 
|   1 |         1 | 2020-10-19 07:00:00 | 2020-10-19 17:00:00 |            9| 
|   2 |         2 | 2020-10-19 07:00:00 | 2020-10-19 17:00:00 |            9| 
|   3 |         3 | 2020-10-19 07:00:00 | 2020-10-19 17:00:00 |            9| 
|   4 |         1 | 2020-10-20 07:00:00 | 2020-10-20 17:00:00 |            9| 
|   5 |         2 | 2020-10-20 07:00:00 | 2020-10-20 17:00:00 |            9| 
|   6 |         3 | 2020-10-20 07:00:00 | 2020-10-20 17:00:00 |            9| 
|   7 |         1 | 2020-10-21 07:00:00 | 2020-10-21 17:00:00 |            9| 
|   8 |         2 | 2020-10-21 07:00:00 | 2020-10-21 17:00:00 |            9| 
|   9 |         3 | 2020-10-21 07:00:00 | 2020-10-21 17:00:00 |            9|
```

**How can I select data like detail below?**
input data alway 1 week( Monday to Sunday).

```
|-----|-------------|-------|--------|-------|--------|-------|--------|-------|--------|------|---------|
|EmpID|total in week|Mon(In)|Mon(Out)|Tue(In)|Tue(Out)|Wed(In)|Wed(Out)|Thu(In)|Thu(Out)|Fri(In)|Fri(Out)|
|-----|-------------|-------|--------|-------|--------|-------|--------|-------|--------|------|---------|
|  1  |           45|  07:00|   17:00|  07:00|   17:00|  07:00|   17:00|  07:00|   17:00| 07:00|    17:00|
|  2  |           45|  07:00|   17:00|  07:00|   17:00|  07:00|   17:00|  07:00|   17:00| 07:00|    17:00|
|  3  |           45|  07:00|   17:00|  07:00|   17:00|  07:00|   17:00|  07:00|   17:00| 07:00|    17:00|
```

Comment: Search the forum by `pivot [mysql]` searching string.

Comment: Or, better, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Please, next time format your code so it's readable to the rest of us.